# Update Table 1 rows with table 2 rows Where table 2 have to fetch from database

Tags: php, mysql

Table 1  (Which needs to be updated)

```
+-----------------+
|name    |qty     | 
+-----------------+
|area    | 1      |
|length  | 2      |
|breadth | 3      |
|width   | 4      |
+-----------------+
```

Table Which needs to be fetched for what values and rows have to be update

```
+-------------------------------------+
|name    | upd_qty | Cart_id |  cid   |
+-------------------------------------+
|area    | 6       |   12    |  1     |
|length  | 8       |   20    |  2     |
|breadth | 11      |   34    |  3     |
+-------------------------------------+
```

How can i do this using php. Help me with this please.
this is the code i have used for my original work. Table 1 & Table 2 have name in common and conditions are 
1 . UPDATE should done for the rows which are fetched from table to with where condition.
2. Table 2 upd_qty will be updated in table 1 qty while fetching data from table 2 where condition.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","medical");
 // Check connection 
   if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
 $query = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE cid='$id' AND 'cart'='$cart_id'";
 $result = $con->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $mediname = $row['name'];
    $mediqty = $row['upd_qty'];
  for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
 $sql="UPDATE stock SET qty='$mediqty' WHERE name='$mediname' AND 
'cart'='$cart_id'";

 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
 {
  die('Error: Failed' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't a place to have people write your code for you. Please lookup "how to ask a question" on stackoverflow for helpful information.

Comment: Your code and table structure totally different bud, please make sure this code.  See your table structure and PHP code as well as your query

Comment: I have updated my code , please review once @webDev

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need this line:

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
```

There's already a "while fetch" loop.

Also, don't use single quotes around identifiers, use backticks if the identifier needs to be escaped.

With this:

```
  ... AND 'cart' = ...
```

`'cart'` will be evaluated a *string literal*, not a column reference.

With this

```
  ... AND `cart` = ...
```

`cart` is an identifier, a reference to a column.

Also, if we can't use prepared statements with bind placeholders, at a minimum, we use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to mitigate SQL Injection vulnerabilities

Also, there's a confusing mix of procedural style and objected oriented style calls...

procedural style

```
mysqli_query($con,$sql)
mysqli_error($con)
```

object oriented style

```
$con->query($query)
$result->fetch_assoc()
```

I recommend you choose one style or the other, and stick to that pattern.

---

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE `cid` = '" 
     . $con->real_escape_string($id)
     . "' AND `cart` = '" 
     . $con->real_escape_string($cart_id)
     . "'";
  $result = $con->query($query);
  if( !$result ) {
      die('Error: ' . $con->error());
  }

  while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
     $mediname = $row['name'];
     $mediqty  = $row['upd_qty'];

     $sql="UPDATE stock SET `qty` = '"
        . $con->real_escape_string($mediqty)
        . "' WHERE `name` = '"
        . $con->real_escape_string($mediname)
        . "' AND `cart` = '" 
        . $con->real_escape_string($cart_id)
        ."'";

     if(!$con->query($sql) ) {
        die('Error: Failed' . $con->error());
     }
  }
```

---

**EDIT**

If there's not a specific reason for the loop, if the goal is just to perform the UPDATE operation and there is not other logic or conditions, we can do the UPDATE in one statement, without a need for multiple query executions:

```
 UPDATE cart c
   JOIN stock s
     ON s.cart = c.cart
    AND s.name = c.name
    SET s.qty = c.upd_qty
  WHERE c.cid = ?
    AND c.cart = ?
```

Personally, I would just do the one UPDATE statement using a prepared statement

```
// connect to mysql
$con = new mysqli(...)
if( $con->connect_error ) {
  die( 'Connect error: ' . $con->connect_error );
}

// update statement
$sql = '
 UPDATE cart c
   JOIN stock s
     ON s.cart = c.cart
    AND s.name = c.name
    SET s.qty = c.upd_qty
  WHERE c.cid = ?
    AND c.cart = ? ';

$sth = $con->prepare($sql);
if(!$sth) {
   die( 'Prepare error: ' . $con->error() );
}
$sth->bind_param('ii',$id,$cart_id);
if(!$sth->execute()) {
  die( 'Execute error: ' . $con->error() );
}
```

Comment: qty isn't updating with this code . I think you havent changed any code except validating the value

Comment: In my case there are no logics but shuold follow where condition ,

Comment: Dude, I was giving some suggestions. The pattern I suggested is "how we do it in PHP".  I removed the goofy `for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {` loop. There's no indication there what `$count` is or why we would need to loop through that many times. Personally, I'd use one prepared statement with bind placeholders.

Comment: can you explain me the how to implement the edit update code in php

Comment: Added example of single UPDATE statement using prepared statement with bind placeholders. Take the static SQL text (the UPDATE statement) to another client and test it there. Supply values in place of the question marks. Get that working. If any changes tweaks are required, get that tested there, and then bring the SQL statement back and plug it into the PHP. (Do we want to replace qty, or do we want to add to the existing value? e.g. `SET s.qty =  ( s.qty + c.upd_qty )`

Answer (score 0):

Code worked for me for what i want exactly is :

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","medical");
 // Check connection 
   if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
 $query = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE cid='$id' AND cart='$cart_id'";
 $result = $con->query($query);


while($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
foreach ($result as $row1){
    $sql="UPDATE stock SET qty='$row1[upd_qty]' WHERE name='$row1[name]'";
     if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
 {
  die('Error: Failed' . mysqli_error($con));
  } 

}
```